# How to setup gridview in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I would like to setup gridview under MyTickets tab.
How can I set this view to have only tickets from username eg 'testuser' ?

In controller I have below code. Table Zgloszenia is my table where I storing all information about tickets (date,username, id etc)

```
 public ActionResult MyTickets(Zgloszenia model)
        {
            if (Session["UserID"] != null)
            {
                test dg = new test();
                var item = dg.Zgloszenia.Where(x => x.UsrUsera == model.UsrUsera).SingleOrDefault();
                return View(item);

            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

        }
```

In view I have this code:

```
@model IEnumerable<Webform.Models.Zgloszenia>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MyTickets";
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}

<h2>MyTickets</h2>

@if (Session["UserID"] != null)
{

    <div>
        Welcome:  <a href="#">@Session["Username"]</a><br />

    </div>
}

@grid.GetHtml(columns: new[] {
    grid.Column("Opis"),
    grid.Column("Priorytet"),
    grid.Column("Srodowisko"),
    grid.Column("NumerTaska"),
    grid.Column("test"),
    grid.Column("Date")
})
```

When I log in to my app and click Tab "MyTicket" I'm receiving below error:

> A data source must be bound before this operation can be performed.

How I can fix this issue and set up view properly ?

Comment: Why not just render a `<table>` directly? I don't see the value in using `WebGrid` here.

Comment: @Dai, this might not be an actual code, it could be a minimal example to highlight the problem OP is having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your action you are selecting a single item, not a collection to enumerate. On the contrary, the WebGrid expects a collection as a data source, so the way you declared things on the view is fine.

To check if that is indeed the issue, simply remove `SingleOrDefault` call in your action. If your `Where` call returns at least one record, you should be able to see it on the page:

```
test dg = new test();
var items = dg.Zgloszenia.Where(x => x.UsrUsera == model.UsrUsera).ToList();
return View(items);
```

Comment: Hi Andrei,

Ok it's working but how can I do that to have grid with all tickets from username eg 'testuser' ?

You know, user has logged to app via thier username and he would like to show only their tickets

Comment: @Tomasz, you are doing pretty much that, you are very close. Search online for how to identify current logged in user

Comment: Yes, I've searched but still I have only empty tables :( Could You help me or give me a hint how to do this ? 
Should I something to do in controller or view ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with Visual studio? If yes, you have to make a dataset. (local or online) You do not have a database at the moment so he saves it nowhere.